# SQL: Get parent and grandparent (CTE or Derived Table)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables to join: tb_assets and tb_locations. Locations is a hierarchy of locations. So an asset may be assigned to "Building A", which may have a parent location of "San Francisco", which may have a parent of "United States"

When I query for an asset, I want to get the parent name, and that location's parent name as well.

Here is the table layout:

[image: table layout]

So using the following, I can easily get the parent name of the current asset, but I've played with derived tables and CTEs and I can't seem to wrap my head around the proper way to accomplish this.

```
SELECT f_assetname, f_locationname
FROM tb_assets
LEFT JOIN tb_locations on f_assetlocationID = f_locationID
```

Here is some sample data

**tb_assets**

```
f_assetID        f_assetname        f_assetlocationID
------------------------------------------------------
1                Building A         1
2                Building B         2
```

**tb_locations**

```
f_locationID     f_locationname     f_locationparentID
------------------------------------------------------
101              United States      NULL
102              San Francisco      101
```

Using the SQL above, we return the following:

```
f_assetname      f_locationname
----------------------------------------
Building A       San Francisco
Building B       San Francisco
```

The output I would like to have would be:

```
f_assetname      f_locationname         f_locationparentname
--------------------------------------------------------------
Building A       San Francisco          United States
Building B       San Francisco          United States
```

Any assistance is appreciated in advance, sincerely.

Thanks,
Beems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another join

```
SELECT a.f_assetname, p.f_locationname as parent, gp.f_locationname as grandparent
FROM tb_assets a
LEFT JOIN tb_locations p on a.f_assetlocationID = p.f_locationID
left join tb_locations gp on gp.f_locationID = p.f_locationparentID
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6353f/3/1)

Comment: like minds think alike, but you may need to alias the second `f_locationname' so that the processor does not squawk about two columns with same name...

Comment: @CharlesBretana Thank you for the hint, fixed.

Comment: Well I'll be, leave it up to me to overcomplicate any problem. I had no idea this was even possible, but it sure does work like a champ! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a self join

```
Select a.f_assetname asset, p.f_locationname parent,
     gp.f_locationname grandParent
From tb_assets a
   Left Join tb_locations p 
       On  p.locationID = a_assetlocationID
   Left Join tb_locations gp 
       On  gp.locationID = p.f_locationParentId
```